# WPF: Address nested styles by key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a fairly complex WPF UserControl that needs a lot of custom styling, and several different styles for the same control types. The same styles are not used in any other places.

**I would like to use nested styles (using `Style.Resources`) as a sort of namespacing mechanism as follows:**

Example user control:

```xml
<UserControl Style="{StaticResource AwesomeControl}>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonA}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonB}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How I *want* to define my styles:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl" x:Key="AwesomeControl">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonA"> </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonB"> </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, this does not work. From what I can tell, it does not seem possible to address nested styles by their key. (I have searched around a lot, but cannot find a single example doing something like this.)

I can make it work easily by removing the nesting of styles, keeping them all at top level. However, then I have to change their keys to something like `AwesomeControlButtonA`, etc. to distinguish them from other parts of the application

That does not seem ideal to me.

So my question is:

**Is something like I am trying with the code above possible? If not, are there other ways of namespacing I can use to prevent awkward keys like AwesomeControlButtonA?**

Comment: You can't avoid having `AwesomeControlButtonA` keys or make them to `AwesomeControl.ButtonA`, where `AwesomeControl` can be omitted somehow, because resource key lookup is *plain* dictionary search. You have only *scope* at your disposal (think about it as local variables). If you plan to hold styles globally, then it's going to be `AwesomeControlButtonA`. Consider to e.g. define buttons in the most appropriate scope, so you don't need long key. There is also [BasedOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) to implement kind of inheritance (means less keys)

Comment: Do not forget, this plain dicitonary is building during 'visualization'. So there is no one simple dictionary. Element of VisualTree have different dictionaries based on theres position in visal tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe `DynamicResource` could solve your problem

```
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonA}"/>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonB}"/>
</Grid>
```

In context:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="AW" TargetType="UserControl">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="AB">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BB">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="AR" TargetType="UserControl">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="AB">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BB">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <UserControl Style="{StaticResource AW}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="A" Style="{DynamicResource AB}" />
                <Button Content="A" Style="{DynamicResource BB}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </UserControl>
        <UserControl Style="{StaticResource AR}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="A" Style="{DynamicResource AB}" />
                <Button Content="A" Style="{DynamicResource BB}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </UserControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I did not realise DynamicResource could be used in this way. Thanks for the very illustrative example! (While I didn't downvote, your answer DOES look much more pretty now.) I'll look into this, and if it works for me (/if there are no better answers) will accept yours.

Comment: That's why `DynamicResource` is existed. When you applied `Style` to the `UserControl`, you dynamically changed the `AB` and `BB` style in the `ResourceDictionary`. `DynamicResource` noticed it - because it's an expression, not a hardcoded link -  and refresh itself. StaticResource cannot refresh. It is loaded during XAML parsing, and no way to replace it.