# WPF Styling nested elements from a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666269/styling-nested-elements-in-wpf) SO question, I am trying to style ComboBoxItems as easily as possible. However, I am making a custom style based on ComboBox's default style found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<Style x:Key="MultiComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource MultiComboBoxItem}"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <!--<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />-->
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    ...
    ...
</Style>
.
.
.
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}">
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="First">First</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Second">Second</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Third">Third</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

I added the `<Style.Resources>` bit to the top in hopes to only need one reference here, instead of individually adding it to nested elements, or even needing to add it to the element in the first place. Also, I commented out all of the `OverridesDefaultStyle` Setters.

However, then I get a XAMLparseexception, "Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies". The error makes sense by itself, but I thought since I was targeting `ComboBoxItem`'s it should work. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies

the problematic lines are these:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource MultiComboBoxItem}"/>
</Style>
```

try rewrite them as

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MultiComboBoxItem}">
</Style>
```

or maybe better use `ItemContainerStyle` property:

```
<Style x:Key="MultiComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MultiComboBoxItem}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <!--<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />-->
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />

</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that in the previous question, but the way they acted toward `ItemContainerStyle` made me think it wasn't the right answer for me. Thanks for setting me straight. I'll accept this answer as soon as SO allows me.

Comment: Now my question is, how would I do this for a StackPanel?

Comment: @SanjayCruze, what exactly should be done for StackPanel?

Comment: Applying a style to all children of a stackpanel (instead of a combobox), because stackpanels don't have the `ItemContainerStyle` property. I ended up figuring it out though. In the stackpanel style, I added `<Style.Resources>
      <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MyRadioButton}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"/>
 </Style.Resources>`