# How to set the properties of the child control of Label

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I would like to change the properties of the Border control that is a child of the default Label control.  I have the following style and everything except the changes to the Border control are being shown in the UI

```
<Style x:Key="StandardLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0:0.000}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" >
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4078275/455492) as the basis for what I am trying, but it does not seem to work for me.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got the same default `Label` template as me, the Border has padding set via an attribute, which due to [dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) will override anything done in a style.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Border 
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
        >
```

However, look what value that attribute uses: `Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"`

So it'll use whatever `Padding` its templated parent has. That's the `Label`. So this should do what you want:

```
<Style x:Key="StandardLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
```

That will work for any property where the `Border` has a `TemplateBinding` to a property of the `Label`. Anything else (if `Border` had any useful properties not already accounted for), you could use your local implicit style method; I tested that with a copy of the default style, with the `Background` attribute removed from the Border in the template:

```
<Style x:Key="LabelStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                    >
```

Comment: Would you look at that...I'm making it way more confusing that it has to be.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Out of curiosity how do you view your default templates?

Comment: I created a Label, put the XAML editor in Design mode, rift clicked on the Label, and selected something like "Edit copy" under "Edit Template". I'm on my phone at the moment but it's in there somewhere.